# Not getting a value in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, query, sosl

I am not getting a value in SOQL, while in system debug I am getting only this output :

> cid:ali
>   record:()

Code:

```
 MVImportBatch__c record = [select Id from MVImportBatch__c limit 1];
 string cid =  string.valueOf(String.valueOf(record.Id).substring(0,3));
 System.debug('cid:'+cid);
 List<Task> record1 = new List<Task>();
 record1 = [SELECT Subject FROM Task WHERE Subject LIKE '%+cid+%'];
 System.debug('record:'+record1);
```

Answer (score 6):

Format your input variable with like operator and then use it in SOQL.
Refer below code:

```
MVImportBatch__c record = [select Id from MVImportBatch__c limit 1];
string cid =  string.valueOf(String.valueOf(record.Id).substring(0,3));
System.debug('cid:'+cid);


List<Task> record1 = new List<Task>();
cid = '%' + cid + '%';
record1 = [SELECT Subject FROM Task WHERE Subject LIKE :cid];
System.debug('record:'+record1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dynamic SOQL:
MVImportBatch__c record = [select Id from MVImportBatch__c limit 1];
string cid =  string.valueOf(String.valueOf(record.Id).substring(0,3));
System.debug('cid:'+cid);

List record1 = new List();
record1 = Database.query('SELECT subject FROM task WHERE subject like \'%cid%\'');
System.debug('record:'+record1);

Comment: They're not trying to match the literal string `'cid'`.